# Run program in cmd mode after building from Sublime Text 4

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm using Sublime Text 4 with Python as a build system to compile my py programs.
I want to run the program that I've just compiled in a cmd window (not in the Sublime console) What can I do for that? Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In the accepted answer of the duplicate, the first example of a Windows build system does this.